# WinRT xaml / c# return navigation parameter from page on GoBack

Tags: winrt-xaml

I am trying to create an Entry page, and one of the options is to select an Item. the list can go more than a 1000 and it makes sense to show the search enabled page where the items are listed.
When the user clicks the "select item" from the Edit / create screen, I can pass the navigation parameter to that screen, and on selecting the item i can do a Frame.GoBack(). However, i cant pass any parameter back to the page. Is there a better way to do this?

At the moment I am thinking of using Global variables to store this data :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the LayoutAwarePage.cs class in the Common folder and looking into the:

```
protected virtual void GoBack(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((base.get_Frame() != null) && base.get_Frame().get_CanGoBack())
    {
        base.get_Frame().GoBack();
    }
}
```

to see if you can pass an object?

Comment: The GoBack method doesnt take any arguments. Am i missing your point?

Comment: Sorry thought you could pass an arguments, I'll check to make sure when I have time.